# where can I get Microsoft.Data.Objects

Tags: c#

Where can I download the dll/sdk that contains the Microsoft.Data.Objects namespace it appears that google doesn't know.  Thanks

Comment: What version of Visual Studio are you running and what version of .NET are you targeting?

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for the [Entity Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386871.aspx). Also see [here for getting started](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386876.aspx).

MSDN isn't terribly clear on [this but](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.aspx):

> The System.Data.Objects namespace
>   includes classes that provide access
>   to the core functionality of Object
>   Services. These classes enable you to
>   query, insert, update, and delete data
>   by working with strongly typed CLR
>   objects that are instances of entity
>   types.

Answer (score 1):

There are new pieces to `Microsoft.Data.Objects` in the CTP4 (code first) release of Entity Framework 4.  See http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=4E094902-AEFF-4EE2-A12D-5881D4B0DD3E

That may be what you are looking for??